# Can't access object values in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have a functional React component that I want to return a list of information about a car. The first three lines of the return statement (model, maker, release) load with no problem, but the categories won't load because React says 'category' is undefined.

When I console.log car after it is set in state, the car object has the categories key on it, and I can expand that to show three category objects. I can then expand each of those to show category.id and category.name.

So is there a way to access car.categories.category.name? Is the issue that there are three objects?

```
const CarDetails = () => {
    const {carsId} = useParams();
    const [car, setCar] = useState([])

    const loadCar = () => {
        getOneCar(carsId)
            .then(data => {
                setCar(data)})
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadCar()
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(car)
    }, [car])


    return (
        <>
        <h2>{car.model}</h2>
        <p>Maker: {car.maker}</p>
        <p>Year released: {car.released}</p>
        {/* <p>Categories: {car.categories.category.name}</p> */}
        </>
    )
```

This is what the object looks like

```
"model": Corvette
"maker": Chevrolet
"categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sports"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "category": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Hybrid"
                }
```

Comment: You need to account for your initial state (which is `[]` right now, but should probably be `undefined` unless you want an array). Right now, you try to render the `car` no matter what -- you should only render if you have a value (which happens after the async call)

Comment: Right, initial value for `car` should be like `null` or `undefined` like @jnpdx said. And you should only render if `car` has a value. Add this line: `if (!car) { return null; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think car.categories is an array not an object.
So car.categories.category does not work.
Please try car.categories[0].category, car.categories[1].category, ... like this.

```
<>
  <h2>{car.model}</h2>
  <p>Maker: {car.maker}</p>
  <p>Year released: {car.released}</p>
  {/* <p>Categories: {car.categories.category.name}</p> */}
  <p>Categories: </p>
  {car && car.categories.map(item => {
    return(<span>{item.category.name}</span>)
  })}
</>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `car.categories` is an array, not an object. You cannot read an array by the dot notation. Instead, you must loop through it to access each element, like this:

```js
<>
  <h2>{car.model}</h2>
  <p>Maker: {car.maker}</p>
  <p>Year released: {car.released}</p>
  <p>Categories: </p>
  <ul>
    {car.categories.map((category) => (
      <li>{category.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look "categories" value, you will see its a list. So you can't access `category` by doing `categories.category`.

However, `category[0].category.name` would work as you need to index the list.

Or you can map the list

```
categories.map(item => item.category.name)
```